# Updating specific data in table row from c# form button

Tags: c#, sql, database, forms

I am only trying to update specific columns using the below code.
The column I'm trying to update is called TotalMinutes where the Username is equal to sUsername.

```
string Query = "update fog.athlete set (TotalMinutes) (TotalMinutes='" + iTotal + "'where Username='"+ sUsername +"'";
```

When doing this I get the below error:

> Error in syntax near '(TotalMinutes) (TotalMinutes='85' where username = 'test01'" at line 1

Comment: I think I'm required by some unwritten SO rule to remind you that string concatenated queries such as this are rife for SQL injection attacks. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
string Query = "update fog.athlete set TotalMinutes='" + iTotal + "'where Username='"+ sUsername +"'";
```

Isn't this the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 2):

A SQL update statement looks like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

So I think you have to try:

```
string Query = "update fog.athlete set TotalMinutes='" + iTotal + "'where Username='"+ sUsername +"';";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the query like this;

```
string Query = "update fog.athlete set TotalMinutes='" + iTotal + "', class = '" + lblGrade.Text + "'" where Username='" + sUsername + "'";
```

But i strongly suggest you to use [Parameterised](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx) query instead to prevent SQL Injection Attacks in SQL Server

For Example:

```
        string Query = "update fog.athlete set TotalMinutes=@total where Username=@userNAme";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("constr_here");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@total", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = iTotal;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@userNAme", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userNAme;
```

Comment: The code has worked, thank so much you've literally saved me life

Comment: one last question, How would I now use:

string Query = "update fog.athlete set TotalMinutes='" + iTotal + "'where Username='" + sUsername + "'"

but add 'set class = lblGrade.Text' in the same line to update also

Comment: I'm getting an error regarding sql syntax. I've tried a few things to get it working but with no avail

Comment: See updates `set TotalMinutes='" + iTotal + "', class = '" + lblGrade.Text + "'"`